# Using getClass inside super class

Tags: java

I want to return a string value from `public String getClass()` but I'm getting an error and telling me to change it to

```
public Class<?> getClass()
```

This is the UML

`getClass(): String // return “Animal” as class name`

I put it as

```
public String getClass() {
     return "Animal";
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a different name for the method.

If you use `getClass()` as the method signature, you are overriding `Object::getClass` ... which returns a `Class` object.

- You don't want to override *that* method.
- Even if you wanted to, you can't override it with an incompatible return type.

You have to ignore / moderate what your UML says about the method name here. (Or modify the UML, if that is an option.)  That UML cannot be implemented literally in Java.  It is just not possible.

---

<sup>In fact, the location of this declaration in your superclass is not significant.  You'd get the same problem no matter where you attempted this in your inheritance hierarchy.  (With an instance method.)</sup>